# JavaScript working in IE but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript

```
function onLoadMoneyEarned(size){
    for(var i=1;i<=size;i++){
        var countStr1 = 'howOften__JB1_'+i;
        var countStr2 = 'howOften__JB2_'+i;
        var countStr3 = 'howOften__JB3_'+i;
        var countStr4 = 'howOften__JB4_'+i;

        var hrsPerWeek1 = 'hrsPerWeek__JB1_'+i
        var hrsPerWeek2 = 'hrsPerWeek__JB2_'+i
        var hrsPerWeek3 = 'hrsPerWeek__JB3_'+i
        var hrsPerWeek4 = 'hrsPerWeek__JB4_'+i

        var dropDownValue1 = document.getElementById(countStr1).value;
        var dropDownValue2 = document.getElementById(countStr2).value;
        var dropDownValue3 = document.getElementById(countStr3).value;
        var dropDownValue4 = document.getElementById(countStr4).value;

        var textbox1 = document.getElementById(hrsPerWeek1);
        textbox1.disabled = true;
        var textbox2 = document.getElementById(hrsPerWeek2);
        textbox2.disabled = true;
        var textbox3 = document.getElementById(hrsPerWeek3);
        textbox3.disabled = true;
        var textbox4 = document.getElementById(hrsPerWeek4);
        textbox4.disabled = true;

        if(dropDownValue1=="HR"){
            textbox1.disabled = false;
        }
        if(dropDownValue2=="HR"){
            textbox2.disabled = false;
        }
        if(dropDownValue3=="HR"){
            textbox3.disabled = false;
        }
        if(dropDownValue4=="HR"){
            textbox4.disabled = false;
        }
    }
```

This is the one working in IE..

I am calling the script like this

```
<script  language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){onLoadMoneyEarned("<%=nameLength%>");});
</script>
```

The main function of this script to enable the number of hours text field only if we select hourly in the dropdown beside it..But it is throwing validation errors in Firefox

Any Help appreciated

Comment: What does the HTML look like?  Is it possible that your elements have "name" attributes but not "id" attributes?

Comment: *But it is throwing validation errors in Firefox*. Please give errors a bit more love. Do not ignore or generalize them. They namely contain the answer. If you don't understand them, just copypaste them in your question so that we can explain them for you in layman's terms. Once an error is properly understood, the solution is nothing more than obvious.

Comment: <SELECT NAME="howOften__JB1_1" ID="howOften__JB1_1" CLASS="formNoStyle" validate = "" onChange=enableDisableWeekTextbox1(this.value,this.id);>this is the html format of the dropdown

Comment: Please be sure to type in only numbers for hours.
Please be sure to type in only numbers for hours.
Please be sure to type in only numbers for hours.
Please be sure to type in only numbers for hours. These are teh validation errors for the 4 fields that are coming from the java file so I didnt mention them..

Answer (score 0):

The ending curly braces seems to be missing. Try adding a closing } to the very end of the function onLoadMoneyEarned.